# Order multiple RSS feeds by date with PHP

Tags: php, rss

I would like to print/echo multiple rss feeds with PHP. right now I'm only able to get one rss feed using foreach to grab the data from a feed and break to limit the number of items to two like this:

```
<?php 
// feed URL
$feed = simplexml_load_file('https://dyn.com/blog/feed/');

// items counter
$rssitem = 0;

foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
  $title       = (string) $item->title;
  $rsslink = (string) $item->link;
  $pubDate = (string) $item->pubDate;
  $subpubDate = substr($pubDate, 0,25);
  $publisher = 'dyn.com';

  print '<div>';
  printf(
    '<h2><a href="%s">%s</h2>
      <p>published: %s via </p>     
    ', 
    $rsslink, 
    $title,
    $subpubDate,
  );

  echo '</div>>';

  // limit number of items 
   if (++$rssitem == 2) break;
}
```

What can I use, if I want to export 2 first items from 2 (or more) RSS feeds and sort the data by publishing date (pubDate)?

Comment: Do you want to download and sort all by date and output only the 2 latest, or do you want to download only the 2 first items and sort them by date?

Comment: I want to download x (2 for this example) number of items from different sources and sort output by date...